# CodeIgniter, Message: Undefined variable, Passing data

Tags: codeigniter, variables

**>> My controllerv - verifyregistration**

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class verifyregistration extends CI_Controller {

function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('users_model','',TRUE);
    $this->load->library('email');
}

function index()
{
    //This method will have the credentials validation
    $this->load->library('form_validation');

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('Login', 'Login', 'trim|required|xss_clean|callback_check_database|min_length[6]|strtolower|callback_username_not_exists');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('Haslo', 'Haslo', 'trim|required|xss_clean|min_length[6]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('Powtorz_Haslo', 'Powtorz haslo', 'trim|required|xss_clean|matches[Haslo]|min_length[6]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('Imie', 'Imie', 'trim|required|xss_clean|min_length[2]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('Nazwisko', 'Nazwisko', 'trim|required|xss_clean');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('Email', 'Email', 'trim|required|xss_clean|valid_email|min_length[6]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('Data_urodzenia', 'Data urodzenia', 'trim|required|xss_clean');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('Telefon', 'Telefon', 'trim|required|xss_clean|min_length[8]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('Miasto', 'Miasto', 'trim|required|xss_clean');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('Ulica', 'Ulica', 'trim|required|xss_clean|min_length[6]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('Kod_pocztowy', 'Kod pocztowy', 'trim|required|xss_clean');
    $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<span style="color: red; font-size:    12px; ; line-height: 14px; ">', '</span>');
    $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<li>', '</li>');
    $data['heading'] = "My Real Heading";  

    if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
    {
        $this->load->view('register/register_open',$data);
    }
    else
    {
        return false;  //this is not important
    }
}
```

**>> My view open - register_open**

```
<?php
$this->load->view('mains/header'); 
$this->load->view('login/loggin');
$this->load->view('mains/menu');
$this->load->view('left_column/left_column_before');
$this->load->view('left_column/menu_left');
$this->load->view('left_column/left_column');
$this->load->view('center/center_column_before');
$this->load->view('register/register_view',$data);
$this->load->view('center/center_column');
$this->load->view('right_column/right_column_before');
$this->load->view('right_column/right_column');
$this->load->view('mains/footer');
?>
```

**>>My view - register_view**

```
<?php echo form_open('verifyregistration/index'); ?>
    <form>
        <label for="username">Login:</label>
        <input type="text" size="25" id="Login" name="Login" set_value='Login' /> 
        .
        .
        .

        <legend>
            <input type="checkbox" id="regulamin" name="Regulamin" onclick="this.form.elements['Wyslij'].disabled = !this.checked" /> 
            Akceptuję regulamin serwisu. </legend>

            <label>&nbsp;</label>
            <input type="submit" name="Wyslij" value="Wyslij" disabled="disabled"/>
            <label>&nbsp;</label>

        <legend>
            <<?php echo $heading;?>
        </legend>
    </form>
```

And I have errors:

Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined variable: data
Filename: register/register_open.php
Line Number: 9
this line-> `$this->load->view('register/register_view',$data);`

Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined variable: heading
Filename: register/register_view.php
Line Number: 48
this line-> `<<?php echo $heading;?>`

How I can pass the data to another view?

Comment: First thing to change is class names have the first letter capitalized in the declaration. It should be: class Verifyregistration extends CI_Controller {

Answer (score 4):

In your controller, change

```
$this->load->view('register/register_open',$data)
```

to

```
$this->load->view('register/register_open',array('data' => $data));
```

When you do `$this->load->view('view', $variable)` it takes `$variable` and uses the php function `extract()` to turn the array keys into variables. So, if you want to use the variable `$data` in a nested view, you have to send another array like I did above.

Comment: When I change this line in my controller to: {$this->load->view('register/register_open',array('data' => $data));} Errors are still this same.

Comment: It should work, but to test, please do this: In your `register_open` view, put die(var_dump($data)); as the first line, and see what it outputs.

Comment: when i add this line, I have this error: A PHP Error was encountered

`Severity: Notice  
Message: Undefined variable: data
Filename: register/register_open.php
Line Number: 2`

I add: `die(var_dump($data));`

Comment: So, $data isn't getting passed to that view. If you pass an array with 'data' as a key, it should work...

Comment: I just tested it on my local copy of CI, and it worked. What version of CI are you using?

Comment: Now, everything it`s ok. Thanks for help!